# Can't boot to desktop, when I boot it gets to the console as shown below

Tags: desktop

Not sure what to say, the OS is installed and I've booted to the desktop before, but after turning it off yesterday I haven't been getting past this screen
[image]

Comment: What OS is it? Because it ain't RaspiOS (which has a 5.10.103 kernel).

Answer (score 1):

well ... i have had that when I set autologin via console in raspi-config... If you something do with this, please try

```
sudo raspi-config
```

choose System_Options --> S5 boot/autologin --> B4 Desktop Autologin --> yes --> reboot